# naming convention suggestion for web developement

Tags: naming-conventions

I have implemented a notification bar at the top of my web page. When the user performs an insert,edit,delete. My messages are

`Successfully inserted` // insert or create
`Successfully updated`  // update or edit 
`Successfully deleted`  // delete

Is this ok. Or any other suggestion from user point of view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest giving a meaningful message instead of just saying "Successfully updated"

e.g.

- Your work address was successfully saved.
- User "MuraliVijay CSK" was successfully saved/created

In some cases (if your app casual) you can also be humorous

e.g. In bugzilla search, the app says "Zaro boogs found" if there were not bugs matching your search criteria

Answer (score 1):

I would use "created" instead of inserted. Inserted is too technical for some users

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you could be friendlier?

```
 Created new customer "bill"

 Updated phone record for "bill"

 Removed customer "bill"
```

Two ideas here: 1). use domain-specific terms that the user relates to. 2). Give enough context so that if the user leaves their desk for a while and comes back exactly what they did is displayed. "Insert OK" leaves the question "hmmm, wonder what I inserted."

Answer (score 1):

1. Action "Create or Insert or Add" related to a new entry so you can say "The new entry XXX has been successfully created or inserted or added.".
2. Action "Edit or Modify or Update" related to the existing entry so you can say "The existing entry XXX has been successfully edited or modified or updated.".
3. Action "Delete or Remove" related to the existing entry so you can say "The existing entry XXX has been successfully deleted or removed.".

{Add,Edit,Delete}, {Create, Modify, Remove}, etc can be used, but it is better to choose one set and make use of it consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Also "modified" can be the option for "updated".

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using "created" instead of "inserted", just let the user know what has been modified (eg "Successfully updated your address")

Answer (score 0):

we all have to agree when implementing the web page to the public it is better we remove all technical terms and use the simple to understand words which a first time internet user should be able to understand,

instead of using Successfully Inserted , Updated or deleted i would use the keywords like

Request Processed Successfully. for all types of request.

Answer (score 0):

I would also add the id/key field to the message in case you would like to identify the added/updated/deleted field easily by its key value.